# Terms for Japanese/Western name order

Tags: words, names

Does anybody know of a standard term to describe Japanese and Western name orders (for example, when filling a form):

> John Somelastname ← "Western name order"
>
> Somelastname John ← "Japanese name order"

Short of an exact term for each form, what construct would you use if you had to tell somebody to use one instead of the other? or tell someone which one is which, in a document where both would be present.

To clarify: I am not asking how to say "write first name, followed by last name" or some such step-by-step instruction, but a self-contained descriptive term for the forms themselves.

Comment: I don't think you can tell someone to use one order rather than another. Japanese people with Western-adopted mind romanize their name in Given name-Family name order, whereas people with enough education in scientific field will often romanize their name in Family name-Given name order. And when it comes to proper nouns, the way someone writes his/her name defines the correct way to write. Depending on the person, "Yamada Taro" might be correct. For another "Yamada", the order "Taro Yamada" might be correct.

Comment: If you want to tell people to write parts of their names in a specific order, usually, there are separate columns for each part, being specified for what part it should be filled with.

Comment: If you are mentioning the typical name order defined in the society, there might be terms for that, but then, "Given name-Family name" and "Family name-Given name" are not the only orders found across the world, so there should be a more complicated system of terminology. My guess is that cultural anthropology or sociology might deal with it.

Comment: @sawa Say you're talking to someone and they give you someone else's name (who is not present).  How would you ask for clarification about the order the given and family names were provided?  Sometimes people will provide them in the Western order to "help out" the foreigner; sometimes they are provided in the "natural order" for the speaker/person being discussed, so it's not always easy to assume what the order is.  (I think this is related to Dave's question?)

Comment: @Troyen I wouldn't ask what order it is given in. I would ask which part is the family name and which part is the given name.

Comment: @sawa: indeed, you are right to point out that there is a lot more to names than just "Japanese order" and "western order". Also, I am not actually planning to ask somebody to use one or the other, I was just giving a typical example of what I meant (without having to go in the details of my particular situation).

Comment: About the rest: 1) Japanese administrations very often tend to ask for name as a single field (I suspect because they can't even imagine other formats than typical Japanese last-first name), leading to all sorts of issues when 2) they become adamant about all occurrences of the "name" being exactly the same on all documents: with/without middle names, in one order or the other etc. Hence the need to sometime know the proper terminology to discuss these issues :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about:

> 姓－名の順
>
> 名－姓の順

from the [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A7%93#.E5.90.8D.EF.BC.8D.E5.A7.93.E3.81.AE.E9.A0.86) page

Comment: It is more usual to use 中黒 (・) or no delimiter than using a dash (－).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, is there a reading for delimiters? If not, do we read them in succession or is there a pause in between?

Comment: @Flaw: Usually they are not pronounced, so the phrases are read as せいめいのじゅん or めいせいのじゅん.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague said this:

> Surname order - 苗字{みょうじ}順
>
> Firstname order - 名前{なまえ}順

Or How about:

> Japanese - 和順
>
> Western - 洋順

Comment: I think that is about the sorting order of list of names.

Comment: @sawa, How about 和順 and 洋順? I updated the answer.

Comment: Are those words that you created? I can understand them given the context, but I don't think people can understand what they mean without context.

Comment: @sawa, yes I just created them. hehe