# Correct method for writing full name in English and Japanese?

Tags: names, orthography

First name in English, then Japanese; followed by Last name in English, then Japanese:

> Lucas 「ルーカス」Ramage「ラメージ」

First and last name in English, followed by first and last name in Japanese:

> Lucas Ramage 「ルーカスラメージ」

First and last name in English; followed by last, then first name in Japanese:

> Lucas Ramage 「ラメージルーカス」

**Resources**

- [How should I write my name with an American first name and Japanese last name?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61979/34281)
- [Terms for Japanese/Western name order](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4778/34281)

Comment: ラマージ might be a better translation.

Comment: @JACK That's not the pronunciation that is typically used AFAIK. See USS Ramage, Lawson P. Ramage's Wikipedia entry in Japanese, etc. It's drifted away from the old french enough that one can pretty much discount that pronunciation.

Comment: thank you for the research!

Comment: What is the question? The writings are correct.

Comment: @BJCUAI, in this case, the name actually follows the English origin, (See first entry: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ramage). At least, that is what my family has always taken it to mean, since our ancestors were English, not French. Would that have any bearing on the transliteration?

Comment: @ラメージルーカス If the name doesn't have an established representation in Japanese, you're pretty free in how you represent it in katakana. 'John', for example, is represented as ジョン is Japanese, even though is sounds more like ジャン the way Americans pronounce it. The ジョン 'spelling' has been so ingrained in Japanese, though, that it would be odd to not use that spelling. Your relatively unknown (to Japanese) surname can be represented as you see fit, preferably matching your own desired pronunciation. I believe your current katakana usage most closely matches your own pronunciation.